# Unable to locate Blob Storage in local Development using Azure Storage Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-emulator, azure-storage-files

I installed azure storage `emulator` in devBox as an `service` and it runs under system. I also replaced IP address of blob storage from `127.0.0.1:10000` to devBox IP address. Everything is running perfect. But I am unable to find blob file location in my devBox. I installed `Azure Storage Explorer` as well. Using developent Account Name and Key,I tried to connect my blob storage but it doesn't work. Even in other field as custom End point, I provided devBox IP address but not getting blob storage folder. Can anyone please help me to find file location of blob storage?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by `file location of blob storage`? Are you looking for a directory on your computer where Storage Emulator keeps the blobs?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes I am looking for directory.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the storage emulator uses a local Microsoft SQL Server instance and the local file system to emulate the Azure storage services. By default, the storage emulator uses a database in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB.

I suggest you could install SQL Server Management Studio Express to manage your LocalDB installation. The storage emulator connects to SQL Server or LocalDB using Windows authentication.

Link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

You could find the AzureStorageEmulatorDb as below image shows:
[image]

Then you could select the BlockData table(If you store the file as blockblob).

In the result’s FilePath column you will find the file location.

[image]

Comment: If I execute emulator, then location of directory is exactly same as you mentioned but I host emulator as a service then I didn't find file on that directory.

Comment: Could you please explain more about the devbox environment? Which devbox you have used under your system?